# Filter on ObservableCollection list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, lambda, observablecollection

I am wondering if anyone tell me why the filtering on `Queries` which is a list of `ObservableCollection` does not work in my below code? `Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value))` always has the whole list..no filtering. Is there something wrong with my lambda expression?

ViewModel:

```
namespace DataRetrieval.ViewModel
{
    public class QueriesViewModel:BindableBase
    {
        public QueriesViewModel()
        {
            Queries = new Queries();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {

                    var query = new Query { Name = "Query "+i.ToString() };

                    Queries.List.Add(query);
                }

        }

        private Queries _queries;
        public Queries Queries
        {
            get { return _queries; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _queries, value); }
        }

        private string _filter1;
        public string Filter1
        {
            get { return _filter1; }
            set { 
                SetProperty(ref _filter1, value);
                filterlist(Filter1);
            }
        }
        private void filterlist(string value)
        {
            Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value));
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
  public class Queries : BindableBase
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Query> _list;
        public ObservableCollection<Query> List
        {
            get { return _list ?? (_list = new ObservableCollection<Query>()); }
            set { SetProperty(ref _list, value); }
        }

    }
    public class Query:BindableBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { 
                SetProperty(ref _name, value); 
            }
        }
        private string _type;
        public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _type, value); }
        }
        private QDatatables _tables;
        public QDatatables Tables
        {
            get { return _tables; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _tables, value); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Queries.List = Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value));

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov I get the following error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DataRetrieval.Model.Query>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DataRetrieval.Model.Query>'‌​. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Queries.List = new ObservableCollection<Query>(Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Queries.List.Where()` returns a new value, so either set it back to Queries.List (as @Valera said in his comment), or return it like so:

```
Queries.List = Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value));
```

or

```
return Queries.List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(value));
```

**Edit:** returning wouldn't work because it is inside a void function, and you'd have to change that, or use @Valera's method.

Comment: return statement is not appropriate in this case. Because he calls "void" function.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer if I try the first option , I get the following error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DataRetrieval.Model.Query>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DataRetrieval.Model.Query>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @EthanBrouwer Thanks your answer was close too.